# A pattern to make userId available to a JavaScript without busting the cache

Tags: javascript

I have a web site with few pages.
Some of those pages need userId and userName for whatever processing in JavaScript context.

Note: the user id is not being used for security, and is not being sent back to the server, so spoofing is not an issue.

Question: what is a good way to pass userId and userName to the JavaScript context.

**UPDATE** 
Ideally I would like a generic pattern that can be used for passing any data (e.g. default values for a list sort and filter settings) from the server to JavaScript code, so that I don't solve userId problem differently from problem of passing initialSort and initialFilter values.

Here are some approaches I could think of. I do understand that all of these will work, but I am hoping for an even better pattern. I am **also interested in learning other cons of the solutions I am considering here:**

**1. Pass userId and userName from server as a non-server cookie.**
Cons: cookie will be sent back to the server with every request, which is a waste (not a significant one though).

**2. Use custom headers**
Cons: headers are not available to javascript for the initial request.

**3. Make AJAX request to get data**
Cons: requires extra HTTP trip.

**4. Render data in-line in the initial page HTML**
Cons: busts the cache and makes page non-cacheable.

**5. Switch the polarity (works every time in Star Trek), my favorite so far**
Instead of getting most of HTML on the initial trip - rewrite the page so that initial page returns *mostly* data, while markup is loaded (and cached) separately. E.g.:

```
<html><body>
    <div data-bind="template: 'pages/invoices'" /> <!-- using KO external template to load markup -->
    <script src="require.js"></script>
    <script>
         require([...], function (...) {
             var vm = new PageViewModel('userId-bob', 'Bob Smart'); // <-- content rendered by server
             ko.applyBindings(vm);
         });
</script></body></html>
```

Cons: page is search-crawlers hostile (not an issue in my case).

Comment: Where is most of your data coming from at the moment? Is it being included in the initial page, or loaded later via AJAX? Depending on your situation, *that* data isn't likely cacheable anyway, so I'd  recommend including it with that (it is also likely the case that the userId is useless without the data, and vice versa, so that makes this solution even more suitable).

Comment: Is localStorage a possibility?

Comment: I think making an additional request for the userId and whatnot would be the smallest code change to fix this particular issue. If this same situation keeps coming it, it's worth addressing in a different way --  rendering the data inline in the HTML, or adding some user credentials middleware on the server-rendered templating code. For a 1-off or first-of-it's-kind situation, I think an AJAX request is good enough. Perhaps modify the PageViewModel constructor to fetch the user information if it's not given one? Fix it first & develop a pattern if the situation is recurring.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is have it use sessionStorage.

When a page loads, check the sessionStorage object for the data you need.

If the data do not exist in sessionStorage, then you know that this is the first time the page has loaded (for this session, at least). Then you can perform an ajax call to fetch these data and store them.

If the data do exist in sessionStorage, then you don't need to perform any additional ajax calls.

This ought to reduce you to one and only one additional HTTP trip per session which seems pretty reasonable to me.

Something like

```
if(sessionStorage.userId && sessionStorage.userName) {
    //the data exist, assign them to a global var or pass to the function that needs them
} else {
    //the data do not exist, make an ajax request to get the data and store them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your context, I'd probably put it in a cookie, and not worry about the overhead.

Comment: You could minimize the overhead by using a cookie-less domain to serve your assets.